# Input files relative to main file when using subfiles

Tags: input, paths, subfiles

I'm writing a report where I use the package `subfiles` to include different parts of my report.

```
\input{misc/variables.tex}
```

will include my variables file perfectly and render the subfiles. But if I try to render a subfile it complains about the filepath, as the relative path is different in the subfile.

I would like to use paths relative to the main file, so I can compile just parts of the subfile, while still including files with `\input`. I can't use absolute paths as the report is shared in a repository, where the others don't have the same absolute path.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Isn't it enough to give (again) a relative path in `misc/variables.tex`, starting at `.../misc` now?

Comment: To have a chance to get answers, this will need more detail, and in particular a full minimal working example we can work from.